# How do I replace one comma outside brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text for example:

> I would like to eat a pie, I would like to take the dog out, I would like to swim (pie, dog, swim)

I need a JavaScript RegEx that replaces the `,` with new line outside the `()`
Right now if I use `.replace(/,/g, "\n")` I will get:

```
I would like to eat a pie
I would like to take the dog out
I would like to swim(pie
dog
out)
```

What I need is:

```
I would like to eat a pie
I would like to take the dog out 
I would like to swim(pie,dog,swim)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a regex with a negative lookahead (assuming brackets are balanced and unescaped):

```
str = str.replace(/,\s*(?![^()]*\))/g, '\n');
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/14zZoT/1)

`(?![^()]*\))` is a negative lookahead to assert that we don't have a `)` character ahead without any `(` or `)` characters in-between.

**Code:**

```js
var str = 'I would like to eat a pie,I would like to take the dog out, I would like to swim(pie,dog,swim)';

console.log(str.replace(/,\s*(?![^()]*\))/g, '\n'));
```

Comment: Bold assumption.

Comment: You nailed it, Excellent

Comment: Great , it worked like a charm. Thank you for your quick answer!

Answer (score 2):

Match the `(...)` substrings and match and capture `,` in other contexts to replace later with a newline after checking if Group 1 matched:

```js
var rx = /\([^)]*\)|(,)\s*/g;
var s = "I would like to eat a pie,I would like to take the dog out, I would like to swim(pie,dog,swim)";
var result = s.replace(rx, function($0,$1) {
  return $1 ? "\n" : $1;
});
console.log(result);
```

The pattern matches:

- `\(` - a `(`
- `[^)]*` - 0+ chars other than `)`
- `\)` - a `)`
- `|` - or
- `(,)` - Group 1: a `,` char
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces (to "trim off" the whitespace in front of the line).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HSM0Ot/1).